# Associativity property of the gyrobarycenter

Tags: mg.metric-geometry, hyperbolic-geometry, analytic-geometry

I'm using Ungar's terminology and notations. In the open unit ball of $\mathbb{R}^n$, let $GB(A_1, \ldots, A_N; m_1, \ldots, m_N)$ be the gyrobarycenter of the points $(A_1, \ldots, A_N)$ with gyrobarycentric coordinates $(m_1, \ldots, m_N)$.

I numerically found that (for $n=2$, I have not checked for other values of $n$)
$$
GB(A_1,A_2,A_3;1,1,1) = GB\bigl(GB(A_1,A_2;1,1), A_3; 2\gamma_{(-A_1)\oplus A_2}, 1\bigr)
$$
and
$$
GB(A_1,A_2,A_3;2,2,1) = GB\bigl(GB(A_1,A_2;1,1), A_3; 4\gamma_{(-A_1)\oplus A_2}, 1\bigr).
$$
I also found that there is $p$ not depending on $A_3$ such that
$$
GB(A_1,A_2,A_3;2,1,1) = GB\bigl(GB(A_1,A_2;2,1), A_3; p, 1\bigr)
$$
but I didn't find the expression of $p$.

So it looks like there is an associativity property of the gyrobarycenter. What is this property? There is nothing about that in Ungar's books.

---

## EDIT

The gyrobarycenter (I'm interested in the Möbius gyrovector space) is defined as
$$
GB(A_1, \ldots, A_N; m_1, \ldots, m_N) = 
\frac{1}{2} \otimes 
\frac{\sum m_k \gamma^2_{A_k} A_k}
{\sum m_k \Bigl(\gamma^2_{A_k}-\frac{1}{2}\Bigr)}.
$$
The $\gamma$ factor of a point $X$ is defined by
$$
\gamma_X = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-\Vert X \Vert^2}}.
$$
The scalar multiplication $\otimes$ is defined at page 10 of [this paper](https://ajmaa.org/searchroot/files/pdf/v6n1/v6i1p18.pdf), and the gyroaddition $\oplus$ at page 9.

Comment: It would help to define the gyrobarycenter here, since this question is already the top google hit for that word.

Comment: @MattF. Ok, done.